# How to get attribute from the class in xpath

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul id="globe-welcome" class="fr nav welcome">
<li class="guest" style="display: list-item;">
 <a class="loginlnk">LOGIN</a></li></li></ul>
```

I want to select the WebElement identified by the tag option with text `Auto`. I tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'loginlnk')]"))
```

I encountered this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/select[@id=category]/option[@id=cat2]"} 

Command duration or timeout: 1.52 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

And I tried the other xpath.

What is the right syntax? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below `xpath` :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'LOGIN')]"))
```